# `react` Two routes are output together

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have made two routes.

The problem is that when I go into the 'Main' component, I also get a 'NotFound' page at the bottom.

What should I do?
I've been trying everything for 10 hours and I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

app.tsx

```
import NoProduct from './pages/Product/NoProduct'
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound/NotFound'
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader";
import { QueryClient ,QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query'
import { Route,BrowserRouter, Redirect, Switch, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './pages/Main/Main'

function App() { 
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </Switch>
    </div>
   ) 
 }


export default hot(module)(App);
```

index.tsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are not rendering the `Route` components into the `Switch`, so the `Switch` is returning the `QueryClientProvider` which then renders routes inclusively like a `Router` would.

## Solution

Move the `Switch` *into* the `QueryClientProvider` component so it can match and render single routes as expected.

```
function App() { 
  return (
    <div>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the route path, * means anything, so it will get rendered too with first route

```
<Route path="/error" component={NotFound} />
```

or second solution would be, using `exact`, i hope this will work too

```
<Route exact path="*" component={NotFound} />
```

better solution wouldbe wrapping `Switch` with `QueryClientProvider`

Comment: Once I tried `exact`, it keeps getting output.
If you do it with path="/error" you have to set `Redirect`,


```code<Redirect exact path="*" to="/error" />``` This will take you to the error page on every page.

Comment: @Ashish it should not work like that, what if he want's to redirect to `NotFound` page when route not exist,

Comment: I put `Switch` in `QueryClientProvider` and it worked. thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Switch` component from `BrowserRouter` component, then your code should work,

here is the example:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And if you're using the `BrowserRouter` component, then your `QueryClientProvider` causing the issue, move it outside the `Switch` then it should work.

Comment: `BrowserRouter` already wrapped, i think

Comment: Yes, he edited his question, after my answer @AshishKamble

Answer (score 0):

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
    <Route path="/error" component={NotFound} />

    <Redirect to="/error" />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```